# React: TypeError: Cannot read property 'addHook' of null

Tags: reactjs, heroku, react-dom

I get the following error when running React on my production environment.

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'addHook' of null
 at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/react/lib/ReactDOM.js:106:33)`

What does this mean?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the problem is with debug tools.

[Sources](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/7d7defe30f9e8124185676fa7e2c841ffee17ed5/src/renderers/shared/ReactDebugTool.js#L315)

```
var ReactDebugTool = {
  addHook(hook: Hook): void {
  hooks.push(hook);
}
```

So probably you're still running in the development mode.

> Note: by default, React will be in development mode. To use React in production mode, set the environment variable NODE_ENV to production (using envify or webpack's DefinePlugin). A minifier that performs dead-code elimination such as UglifyJS is recommended to completely remove the extra code present in development mode.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this answer by including the line of code at the top of my application:

`process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'`;

**and then** searching for `process.env.NODE_ENV` and removing any other changes to it in my application.

Comment: hmm, that's what I wrote in the answer, isn't it?)

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I had done an `export NODE_ENV=production; ...` earlier and then forgot about it. Clearing the variable fixed the issue.